# Use cURL with SNI (Server Name Indication)

Tags: php, ssl, curl, sni

I am trying to use cURL to post to an API that just started using SNI (so they could host multiple ssl certs on 1 IP address).

My cURL stopped working as a result of this move to SNI. They explained that it's because cURL is getting *.domain-a.com back instead of *.domain-b.com so the SSL fails.

This seems to be a bug in cURL because the API URL has no errors when visited from a browser.

Using this code, it does work:

```
exec('curl -k -d "parameters=here", https://urlhere.com/', $output);
print_r($output);
```

However, using -k is bad because it doesn't verify the SSL cert.

Using this code, does NOT work:

```
exec('curl -d "parameters=here", https://urlhere.com/', $output);
print_r($output);
```

So my question is, how can I use curl with SNI and still verify the SSL (not have to use -k). Is there another setting in PHP or a cURL option I can set to work around this?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

To be able to use SNI, three conditions are required:

- Using a version of Curl that supports it, at least 7.18.1, according to the [change logs](http://curl.haxx.se/changes.html).
- Using a version of Curl compiled against a library that supports SNI, e.g. OpenSSL 0.9.8j (depending on the compilation options some older versions).
- Using TLS 1.0 at least (not SSLv3).

Note that Curl's debug code (`-v`) only displays the major version number (mainly to distinguish between SSLv2 and SSLv3+ types of messages, see [`ssl_tls_trace`](https://github.com/bagder/curl/blob/9547be37c252416f856fea664ff91c4fbfd86c2c/lib/ssluse.c#L1383)), so it will still display "SSLv3" when you use TLS 1.0 or above (because they're effectively SSL v3.1 or above, 3 is the same major version number).

You could check that your installed version of curl can use SNI using Wireshark. If you make a connection using `curl -1 https://something`, if you expand the "Client Hello" message, you should be able to see a "`server_name`" extension.

I'm not sure which SSL/TLS version is used by default (depending on your compilation options) when you use `curl` without `-1` (for TLS 1.0) or `-3` (for SSLv3), but you can try to force `-1` on your command, since it won't work with SSLv3 anyway.

Comment: If you want to use libcurl, set `CURLOPT_SSLVERSION` to `1` (to be equivalent to `-1` on the command line).

Comment: For me, it was having an old version of cURL installed. Updating it fixed it.

Comment: Note that curl on Mac OS X (as of Yosemite) does not send SNI when used with -k or --insecure.

Answer (score 75):

Along with the required library and Curl version, the request should use resolve to send SNI in the curl:

```
curl -vik --resolve example.com:443:198.18.110.10 https://example.com/
```

Comment: In my case I was accessing the server by IP.  The certificate was downloaded by accessing the same server, by IP, with Firefox.  If I trusted the certificate in my Mac's Keychain, then everything worked accessing it by IP and without validating the certificate in cURL.  But when I removed that certificate from Keychain and tried to validate it in cURL, I kept getting "verification failed" errors until I resolved that IP to the name I had downloaded the original certificate from, as this answer suggests.