# Azure Website using the wrong SSL certificate when called using curl (Error 51)

Tags: php, azure, curl, ssl, https

I have a project on Azure Websites, hosting an API which should be accessible only using HTTPS, using my custom .com domain. A-Records were created to the .com domain, which is working properly. The SSL Certificate were bought, uploaded and the SSL bindings are set-up correctly in the management panel.

When I access a method of the API using IE/Chrome/FF, the proper certificate (issued for my .com domain) is displayed. When I access it using the following PHP code using curl, I get an error message as if the server responded with the default *azurewebsites.com certificate, which fails as the request was made to the .com domain.

```
$ch = curl_init('https://mydomain.com/api/v1/method');
$cabundle = dirname(__FILE__).'/ca-bundle.crt';

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonRequest);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cabundle);

$content = curl_exec($ch);
$curlInfo = curl_getinfo($ch);
```

(as you can see, I'm already using the CA file required to validate the certs, if I run a `file_exists` passing the `$cabundle` variable as parameter, it returns true)

The error I get:

```
curl error 51: SSL: certificate subject name '*.azurewebsites.net' does not match target host name 'mydomain.com' content
```

As already told, if I access the same URL using a browser, the correct certificate for my .com domain is the one shown in the view certificate details screen.

What should I do either for curl requesting/validating the right certificate, or Azure respond with the correct certificate for the domain requested?

PS: setting `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to `false`, or `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` to `0` or `1` are not options, security is essential to this project, and a MITM attack could be very harmful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably there are several certificates behind the same IP and you need to use SNI (server name indication, e.g. the server name is sent within the SSL handshake). Not all versions of curl support SNI, please check [Use cURL with SNI (Server Name Indication)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941703/use-curl-with-sni-server-name-indication).

Comment: Indeed, azure websites uses SNI. Researching now to check whether I'll be able to do this using the version of curl installed in the server being used. Thanks!

Comment: In the upper tiers Azure web sites does offer [IP based SSL](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate/) with custom certificates at some [additional cost](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/web-sites/#ssl-connections).