# cURL not working on web server with SNI

Tags: php, curl, nginx, cron, sni

I have an RSS reader web application installed on my server, which uses TLS full time via SNI (nginx). I'm trying to set up a curl command in cron to automatically refresh the feeds, but I'm getting problems.

Running the command that the RSS reader provides for cron jobs: `curl -L -s --user-agent 'Fever Refresh Cron' -k 'https://fever.cconover.com/?refresh'`

I get the HTML of the default host on my nginx server, instead of the proper response from my RSS reader.

Running `curl -I https://fever.cconover.com?refresh` I get the following result:

`curl: (51) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'fever.cconover.com'`

This only happens when I run these commands on the server where the RSS reader is hosted. If I execute them from any other machine, they work properly.

I've checked whether the IP my server has for that address is incorrect, but running `ping fever.cconover.com` provides the public IP of my server.

I recently migrated to this server off of one that, I thought, was configured the same way this one is, and it worked fine on the old server. I unfortunately don't have access to the old server anymore so I can't compare the two. However, I know that these exact commands used to work fine.

How can I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use cURL with SNI (Server Name Indication)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941703/use-curl-with-sni-server-name-indication)

Comment: I don' think it is a duplicate. I have the latest version of cURL from the Ubuntu repository, which worked fine for me on my other server.