# cURL displays SSLv3 instead of TLSv1

Tags: c++, ssl, curl

Why does cURL 7.19 display SSLv3 during handshake if SSL is disabled by curl_easy_setopt function?

```
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1);
```

cURL output:

```
CURL Info: SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
CURL Info: SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
CURL Info: SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
CURL Info: SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
CURL Info: SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
CURL Info: SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
CURL Info: SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
CURL Info: SSLv3, TLS handshake, Unknown (4):
CURL Info: SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
CURL Info: SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
CURL Info: SSL connection using DES-CBC3-SHA
```

Is it OK that cURL displays "SSLv3"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll quote [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12942331/372643) (to a different question):

> Curl's debug code (`-v`) only displays the major version number
>   (mainly to distinguish between SSLv2 and SSLv3+ types of messages, see
>   [`ssl_tls_trace`](https://github.com/bagder/curl/blob/9547be37c252416f856fea664ff91c4fbfd86c2c/lib/ssluse.c#L1383)),
>   so it will still display "SSLv3" when you use TLS 1.0 or above
>   (because they're effectively SSL v3.1 or above, 3 is the same major
>   version number).

If you want to make sure you're using the right version, you should probably check the [return value from `setopt`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSLVERSION.html).

In addition, you could use the trace option to look at the handshake in details:

> ```
> == Info: SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
> => Send SSL data, 512 bytes (0x200)
> 0000: 01 00 01 fc 03 03
> ```

The 5th byte will be the major revision number (03 here), the 6th will be the minor revision number.

- (03, 00) is SSLv3
- (03, 01) is TLSv1.0
- (03, 02) is TLSv1.1
- (03, 03) is TLSv1.2

Comment: Bruno, thank you for the answer. Is there any official note than curl displays SSLv3 using TLS?

Comment: I'm not aware of any documentation besides this source code. If this is really an issue, it shouldn't be too hard to provide a patch that indicates the full version (with minor number).